# Flutter Question: OnTap and OnHover works together?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

Im trying to use onHoover and onTap of a inkwell widget, but not OnHoover together with onTap doesn't work

I tried various combination, but with no success. please help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question,

but you can't use `onHover` without `onTap`.

But you can make `onTap` like this `onTap: () {} // <- doesn't do anything when clicked`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to archive but may be you can use GestureDetector widget see if it can work